# Socket, asynchronous data receiving and exception while invoking method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to implement some protocol for instant messaging so I'm using Socket class. When Socket receive any data packet from server I'm trying to fire up an event which inform my other class that there is some data to work with. But when I'm trying to call method from event handler's method I get an error: ".NET Compact Framework does not support invoking delegates asynchronously"

Here is some code that I'm working with. I left a comment on line where exception occurs.

```
public class ClientSocket3
{
    Socket _socket;

    private const int ConnectionTimeout = 5000;
    private static ManualResetEvent connectedDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public OnReceiveHandler3 OnReceive
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Connect(IPEndPoint endPointAddress)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(args_Completed);
        args.RemoteEndPoint = endPointAddress;
        args.UserToken = _socket;

        _socket.ConnectAsync(args);

        if (connectedDone.WaitOne(ConnectionTimeout))
        {

        }            
    }

    void args_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Connect)
        {
            connectedDone.Set();

            Debug.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
        else if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Receive)
        {
            if (OnReceive != null)
            {
                OnReceive(this, null);
            }
        }
        else if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Send)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Sent... Waiting for answer");

            _socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
        }
    }

    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs sendArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        sendArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(args_Completed);
        sendArgs.SetBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);

        _socket.SendAsync(sendArgs);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _socket.Close();
    }
}

public delegate void OnReceiveHandler3(object sender, byte[] receivedData);
```

```
 class XYZ
    {
            private ClientSocket3 client;

            public void Connect(IPEndPoint ipep)
            {

                try
                {
                    client = new ClientSocket3();
                    client.Connect(ipep);
                    client.OnReceive += new OnReceiveHandler3(testReceived);

                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    // todo
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            private void Send(byte[] data)
            {
                    _client.Send(data);
            }

            private void testReceived(object sender, byte[] e)
            {
                    RecvData(e); **// here exception is thrown: Exception: .NET Compact Framework does not support invoking delegates asynchronously**
            }

            private void RecvData(byte[] data) 
            { 
                //....
            }
    }
```

Exception is thrown right after calling Send() method from XYZ class. Of course before sending anything I'm calling Connect method so I'm connected to server.

I've tried to work with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() and System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() but with no luck - perhaps I'm using them in a wrong way.

Any ideas how to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

**Updated**;

Exception - stack:

```
   at Test.IM.XYZ.testReceived(Object sender, Byte[] e)
   at Test.Net.ClientSocket3.args_Completed(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompletedInternal(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.InvokeCallback(Boolean asyncCompletion)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SocketAsyncRequestManager.WorkerThread.doWork()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SocketAsyncRequestManager.WorkerThread.doWorkI(Object o)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Exception class: System.NotSupportedException.

In Data is System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal but count is 0

Comment: Could you post the whole exception including the stack trace?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the main post.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how to fix this specific issue, but for your purpose you might want to take a look at the UdpSingleSourceMulticastClient which is part the lib as with 7.1.

see msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpsinglesourcemulticastclient(v=vs.95).aspx

Good Luck!

Comment: Server is using TCP protocol so I must also use TCP.

Comment: Ok, missed that requisite. maybe this article helps you a bit:http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-networking.aspx